# Nginx mobile redirection fails

Tags: nginx

When I go to http://domain.com the mobile redirection works but when I go to some other pages it fails and serves the original link.

```
       location / {

        if ($http_user_agent ~* "(iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry)" ) {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/m$request_uri;
        }

       index index.php;

    }

    location /m/ {
        index index.php;

    }
```

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration

Answer (score 0):

You have to say to nginx where is your root of your server_name, so after the mobile detection you have to say to nginx where is the root of desktop.